# Is there a way to visualize many y-Axis-Data with one x-Axis Data (with Highcharts and php)

Tags: php, highcharts

My Problem is that, i dont see the y-Axis data (Temp or Humidity in my case).
I got the x-Axis and it shows (only one Month only). (My comments are in german...)

i would apreciate if someone can help me to solve this or give me hints on how i can solve it.

my goal is to visualize every data, but having the month name every single y-Axis-Data, it will get confusing, thats why i only display one month and the data that were captured or made in (Temp and Humidity from DHT11) should be displayed on y-Axis.

but looking at the table from highcharts there is no data:
first picture is hole diagramm + table from highcharts
[image: [diagramm-highcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhz98.png)]

the data i saved previously (var data... in code, only displayed a few, i cut some data because it was a bit more...)

```
       {"xAxis":["November 2022","December 2022"],"yAxis1":[{"name":"November 2022","data":[22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,22,23,23,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23]},{"name":"December 2022","data":[25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,26,27,27,26,26,27,26,27,27,26,27,27,2726,0,26,0,26,0,0,0,26,0,26,0,0,0,26,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19]}],"yAxis2":[{"name":"November 2022","data":[37,38,38,79,95,95,95,95,82,74,71,46,45,38,38,38,37,40,40,39]},{"name":"December 2022","data":[43,43,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,38,39,39,39,38,38,39,38,38,38,38,39,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,35,0,35,0,35,0,0,0,35,0,35,0,0,0,35,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,62,53,53,53,54,54,54,53,54,53,54,53,54,53,54,54,54,53,54,54,53,54,53,53,53,53,53,53]}]}
```

this is the code (i get all data from database and saved it):

```
<?php
// Verbindung mit der MySQL-Datenbank herstellen
$con = mysqli_connect('ip', 'root', 'root', 'Sensordata');

$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%M %Y') AS datetime, temp, hum FROM temp_humidity";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

// Array erstellen, um die Daten aus der Datenbank zu speichern
$data = array();

// Schleife durch die Daten in der Datenbank
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Datum (Monat) und Zeitstempel des Datensatzes speichern
    $datetime = $row['datetime'];
    $timestamp = strtotime($datetime);

    // Wenn das Array für den Monat noch nicht existiert, erstelle es
    if (!isset($data[$timestamp])) {
        $data[$timestamp] = array(
            'xAxis' => $datetime,
            'yAxis1' => array(),
            'yAxis2' => array()
        );
    }

    // Füge die Y-Werte (Temperatur und Feuchtigkeit) dem Array hinzu
    $data[$timestamp]['yAxis1'][] = (int)$row['temp'];
    $data[$timestamp]['yAxis2'][] = (double)$row['hum'];
}

// Die Daten für das Diagramm aufbereiten
$xAxis = array();
$yAxis1 = array();
$yAxis2 = array();
foreach ($data as $datetime => $values) {
    $xAxis[] = $values['xAxis'];
    $yAxis1[] = array(
        'name' => $values['xAxis'],
        // Überprüfe, ob die Werte im Array für die Y-Achse Integers sind. Falls nicht, konvertiere sie.
        'data' => array_map(function ($value) { return is_int($value) ? $value : (int)$value; }, $values['yAxis1'])
    );
    $yAxis2[] = array(
        'name' => $values['xAxis'],
        // Überprüfe, ob die Werte im Array für die Y-Achse Doubles sind. Falls nicht, konvertiere sie.
        'data' => array_map(function ($value) { return is_double($value) ? $value : (double)$value; }, $values['yAxis2'])
    );
}

// Daten für das Diagramm in einem Array zusammenfassen
$chartData = array(
    'xAxis' => $xAxis,
    'yAxis1' => $yAxis1,
    'yAxis2' => $yAxis2
);

// Datenarray in JSON-Format konvertieren, um sie in Highcharts verwenden zu können
$json_data = json_encode($chartData);

// Datenarray in JSON-Format konvertieren, um sie in Highcharts verwenden zu können
//$json_data = json_encode($data);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SensMo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Highcharts-Bibliothek importieren -->
    <script src="highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="highcharts/js/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="highcharts/js/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

    <!-- Diagrammbereich definieren -->
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

    <pre>
       <?php print_r($json_data); ?>
    </pre>

    <!-- Diagramm erstellen -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        // Daten aus dem JSON-Array verwenden
        var data = <?php echo $json_data; ?>;
        // Diagramm erstellen und in den definierten Bereich einfügen
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                //type: 'scatter' // Diagrammtyp (XY-Diagramm)
                //type: 'line' // Diagrammtyp (Linie)
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Device pi-002 Temperaturverlauf' // Titel des Diagramms
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: data.xAxis, // X-Achse verwendet die Werte aus dem 'datetime'-Array
                title: {
                    text: 'Zeit'
                }
            },
            yAxis: [{
            // Erste Y-Achse zeigt die Temperaturen an
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperatur (C°)'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '°C'; // Werte in C° anzeigen
                    }
                }
            }, {
            // Zweite Y-Achse zeigt die Feuchtigkeit an
            opposite: true,
                title: {
                    text: 'Feuchtigkeit (%)'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '%'; // Werte in % anzeigen
                    }
                }
            }],
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical', // Legenden-Bereich vertikal anordnen
                align: 'right', // Legenden-Bereich rechtsbündig ausrichten
                verticalAlign: 'middle' // Legenden-Bereich mittig ausrichten
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Temperatur', // Name der Datenreihe (wird im Legenden-Bereich angezeigt)
                data: data.yAxis1, // Daten für die Y-Achse verwenden
                color: '#ff0000' // Farbe der Linie (rot)
            }, {
            name: 'Feuchtigkeit', // Name der Datenreihe (wird im Legenden-Bereich angezeigt)
            data: data.yAxis2, // Daten für die Y-Achse verwenden
            color: '#0000ff', // Farbe der Linie (blau)
            yAxis: 1 // Verwendung der zweiten Y-Achse
            }]
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

well i can visualize every single x-Axis and y-Axis data...
but when i try this way, highcharts cant or use the data i saved in a wrong way (data table from highcharts)

i wanted to know if someone knows the problem/mistake i made or give me hints how i could solve this problem.
(1 Month - many data | i searched on highcharts.com but i didnt find anything | what works is every date (Month) and every y data (temp and humidity))
[image: [diagramm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs6rz.png)]

maybe i searched wrong but i would appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to show your data, but in general you need to adapt the the series structure required by Highcharts. You can for example convert the part of your data structure in the way below:

```
  const series = [
    {
      name: "Temperature",
      data: []
    },
    {
      name: "Feuchtigkeit",
      data: []
    }
  ];
  const categories = data.xAxis;

  data.yAxis1.forEach((dataObj, index) => {
    dataObj.data.forEach((value) => {
      series[0].data.push([index, value]); // x,y
    });
  });
```

---

**Live example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wild-7n1w54?file=/index.html

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: Thank you ppotaczek, for the code examples and also the further information you send.